# Извлечения картинок из твиттов

Tags: php, парсер, twitter, twitter-api

Я использую Standart API Твиттера для извлечения картинок из твиттов. Для этого я использую конструкцию

```
$utimeline = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", ["screen_name" => "$_GET[q]", "count" => COUNT_TWITTS]); 
$utimeline=json_decode(json_encode($utimeline), TRUE);
```

из библиотеки twitteroauth для php. Примечательно, что если картинка находится в https://pbs.twimg.com/media/, то она имеется в подмассивах массива $utimeline. А если картинка лежит в https://pbs.twimg.com/ad_img/, то ее нет ни в одном подмассиве. Кстати, прямой парсинг твиттов на php дает аналогичный результат.

Вопрос: Какими средствами API Твиттера я должен пользоваться для решения задачи извлечения картинок?

Если исследовать запросы с помощью вкладки Network средства отладки Chrome, то окажется, что адрес нужной картинки приходит в ответ на такой запрос http://prntscr.com/qdi89n. Причем 22903812 - это ИД юзера, который публиковал твит. Но достучаться по этому адресу, даже если отправлять подобные этим http://prntscr.com/qdiaav заголовки, не удается. Кстати, в документации API Twitter об адресе https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/profile/ ничего нет, хотя, например, 
https://ads-api.twitter.com/6/accounts/:account_id/cards/image_app_download инфа имеется.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что ad_img - это рекламная картинка. Вы уверены, что оно вам нужно?

Comment: Уверен. Вот пример картинки - https://pbs.twimg.com/ad_img/1100828604211040256/Q8LsMZsP?format=jpg&name=orig. Другое дело, что Арсенал ее туда по незнанию закинул.

Comment: В будущем старайтесь вставлять код, ответы от сервера и другую техническую информацию текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: Хорошо. Просто там много текста было.

Comment: вопрос актуален и для меня автор, вы не нашли ответ?

Comment: Увы, пока не нашел. А у вас, коллега, идеи и наработки есть?